# A Linguist in a Cave

Tags: riddle, word

I am but a linguist that lives in a cave.
I talk with visitors from the central city.
When the dragon comes, I invite him inside.
The lions stay out, but gain trust and enter.
Merchants and messengers come in to rest.
Politicians peer outside, but remain indoors.

*What am  I?*

Hint:

> Do not take the lines very seriously, they are abstract (at least in wording).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the wording here conjures up images of:

> a **tongue** in a mouth.

*I am but a linguist that lives in a cave.*

> The 'linguist' is the **tongue**, which is particularly appropriate given that a linguist is an individual who studies *language* (a key role of the tongue, and also a synonym of 'tongue'). The 'cave' is the **mouth**.

*I talk with visitors from the central city.*

> The tongue enables a person to talk upon receiving signals ('visitors') from the brain ('the central city').

*When the dragon comes, I invite him inside.*
*The lions stay out, but gain trust and enter.*
*Merchants and messengers come in to rest.*

> These lines appear to concern things that might be put into the mouth in some capacity - possibly:
>
>  - 'The dragon' is a toothbrush - a large object for which the tongue must move aside ('invite him inside') when brushing one's teeth.
>
>  - 'The lions' may well be other slightly smaller items like fingers, allowed inside (to bite nails, suck a thumb, etc.) after a quick check to be sure they are clean (i.e. they need to 'gain trust').
>
>  - The 'merchants and messengers' are food, drink, medicines, etc. - things that have something to pass on (nutrients, water, medication, etc.) to the body like how a merchant passes on wares or a messenger their message. Once they come into the mouth they usually proceed on to the stomach and stay ('rest') inside the body to be processed and digested.

*Politicians peer outside, but remain indoors.*

> These 'politicians' are the **teeth**, sitting in ordered rows surrounding the tongue, like MPs in a Parliament or senators in a Senate. They don't usually leave the mouth (they 'remain indoors').

Comment: *"a linguist is an individual who speaks one or more languages"* this hurts

Comment: Yes! The reasonings behind the words are not what I had in mind at all but they are very well done and make sense! As for the actual reasons, rot13(Gur "y" fbhaq unf gur gbathr tb bhg bs gur zbhgu, orgjrra gur grrgu, be "bhgfvqr".)
"Linguist" might not have been the best term to use, but at least it was understood.
Good job!

Comment: @melfnt Haha, oops - that was a hastily scrawled definition; will edit to give the true linguists their proper due! ;-)

Comment: @Stiv I think that you made your definition even worse with your last edit. Then I checked Merriam-Webster and it turns out their definition is wrong too -- I'm astonished

Comment: @melfnt Care to share your preferred definition?

Comment: @Stiv sure: it's a person who studies language. I wanted to include a link about the linguist-vs-polyglot question but maybe it's considered spam?

Comment: @melfnt I've implemented the proposed modification and excised any reference to miscellaneous languages, rendering the 'polyglot' inclusion surplus to requirements :)

Comment: Yea, I would have thought that the phrases would at least refer to the tongue position for making various sounds, IPA-style.

Comment: @WoomyRogue Interesting - that's not my experience at all! (I would have described that scenario as putting the tongue just behind the top teeth - it never goes 'outside'. Although I'm fully aware that [some other people](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-u5WLJ9Yk4) *definitely* do as you suggest...)